# Extract matching line after another match occurred using shell

Tags: shell, csv, pattern-matching

I've looked around but I'm not able to find an answer for this.

I have some CSV files in this form:

```
* COMMENT
* Another comment 
100 ; 2029 ; 0.18 ; 0.45 ; 0.00015 ; 0.1485 ; 0.03 ; 1 ; 1 ; 2 ; 344 ; 100 ; 100 ; 

* Comment
* Comment

* ZT vector
0; 742; p; nan
1; 367; p; nan
2; 125; p; nan
3; 1; d; nan

* KS vector
0; 125; p; 33.3773
1; 742; p; 290.274
2; 1; d; 290.274
3; 367; p; 340.774



*Total time: 3.98785
```

I would like to extract the line that contains the pattern `d;` but only the one after the line `* KS vector`.

So in this case I want an output like this:

```
2; 1; d; 290.274
```

Not like this:

```
3; 1; d; nan
2; 1; d; 290.274
```

In every CSV file there's going to be only one line containing `d;` after `* KS vector` and one between `* ZT vector` and `* KS vector`.

How can I do this using the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '/KS vector/{f=1} f==1&&/d/' file
2; 1; d; 290.274
```

Explained:

```
awk '                
/KS vector/ { f=1 }  # after this record flag up
f==1 && /d/          # if flag is up and we see d, output
' file
```